# Why am I getting this error: unknown attribute: data_changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, models, vestal-versions

I get this error and I don't know how to debug it.  It occurs it seems at the 'save' method in my create action for my controller:

I **think** I started getting problems when I deployed vestal_versions:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2906:in `assign_attributes'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2902:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2902:in `assign_attributes'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2775:in `attributes='
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2473:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:162:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:162:in `build_association'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:425:in `create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2178:in `with_scope'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:424:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:424:in `create_record'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:245:in `create'
/home/timothy/.bundler/ruby/1.8/vestal_versions-2773ee610767/lib/vestal_versions/creation.rb:43:in `create_version'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do any required rake tasks by vestal versions? Did you rake db:migrate?

Comment: yes -- I removed versioned from one of the associations for now...but know this has been a problem